# How to call strophejs-plugin-chatstates from service?

Tags: angular, chat, strophe, strophe.js

I have installed strophejs-plugin-chatstates to send composing state of user in one-to-one chat. There is a connection present in my code with local strophe

```
this.connection = new Strophe.Connection(`${EJABBERD_URL}/bosh`,
  { mechanisms: [] });
```

strophejs-plugin-mam, it is used as below

```
this.connection.mam.query(jid, options);
```

But I am getting error if I send composing state using

```
this.connection.chatstates.sendComposing(jid, type);
```

**Error is:**

```
ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'sendComposing' of undefined
```

Am I writing it wrong?
Or How to connect chatstates with my service?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Will have to add that particular node_module's path in angular.json file to make connection.